# Single JMS queue to deliver work to work nodes once and only once?

Tags: spring, jms, activemq-classic

- On Activemq 5.9.0
- Spring JMS 3.2.2.RELEASE
- JDK 1.7.0_51

When i set up a queue A in activemq, and then consume from queue A from consumers C1, C2, C3, C4 and C5... How can I make it so that all messages pulled off of queue A are always only pulled off once?

These 5 consumers are worker threads that pull messages off and do work on them.

I cannot have C1 and C3 both pulling the same messages, that would cause problems.

It seems Activemq out of box causes all sorts of duplicates. Is there a simple config I can put in without having to go through a bunch of guaranteed delivery configurations?

I see this link here: http://www.atomikos.com/Publications/ReliableJmsWithTransactions

Anyone have some quick config + example of getting that situation working with activemq + spring jms?

I'm using the default activemq.xml file.

Here is my spring configuration for the JMS:

```
<bean id="jmsFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
        destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
        <bean class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
            <property name="brokerURL">
                <value>tcp://localhost:61616</value>
            </property>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
<bean id="myJmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory">
            <ref local="jmsFactory" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

I have Spring JmsTemplate and I start by having 5 consumers read from Queue A using the `JmsTemplate.recieve` method.

```
jmsTemplate.setReceiveTimeout(JmsTemplate.RECEIVE_TIMEOUT_INDEFINITE_WAIT);
msg = jmsTemplate.receive("myqueue");
```

Then from a I use the `JmsTemplate.send` method to send a message to the Queue A.

I expected that a message would be pulled off by one and only one consumer. But it's not doing that, i'm seeing duplicate messages.

Do I need to use transactions?

Comment: To me that sounds like you are confusing topics and queues. If you have 5 concurrent consumers for a queue, a message will be delivered to exactly one of the five consumers. You need to share more info on how you set up the consumers.

Comment: hi Ralf. I added some more beef to the end of my question. Let me know if that answered your question thanks for the help.

Comment: Transactions are not necessary. How you end up with the duplicates I cannot say. Post the relevant code where you set up the template. Also which Spring and ActiveMQ versions do you use? When you run your tests, does the ActiveMQ web console show the expected queues and number of consumers? Via JMX you can check more details like number of messages that have been sent via a particular queue. Do the numbers match your expectation?